# Script for running port-forward automatically

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, makefile, sh

I want to create a script that will run `port-forwarding` for a pod automatically, for specific pod name(app3, I've multiple apps in this namespace and I need to run just for `app3` ) when I run this script.

e.g.

`kubectl port-forward pods/app3-86499b66d-dfwf7  8000:8000  -n web`

I've started with

`kubectl get pod -n webide-system | grep app3`

The output is:

`app3-86499b66d-dfwf7                                 1/1     Running     0          18h`

However,Im not sure how to take the output, which is the pod name and run the port forwarding to it
The following in bold is constant

**pods/app3**-86499b66d-dfwf7

And this is changing for each deployment

```
-86499b66d-dfwf7
```

Any idea how to make it works with a script?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a NodePort-type Service, instead?  You can also `kubectl port-forward service/app3` (but note it still under the hood targets a single specific pod).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
POD_NAME=`kubectl get pod -n webide-system | grep app3 | sed 's/ .*//'`

kubectl port-forward pods/$POD_NAME  8000:8000  -n web
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @J.Schultke: Thank you, I'm sure I'll like it here. I feel that this solution is short and simple enough that it is self-explanatory. To expand on it, I would have to divide the problem into two parts and address them separately; apart from being pedantic, this would force me to vote to close the question under the "one Q per Q" rule.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @Beta is correct, but I would like to show you yet another approach.

You can expose the pod using a Service:

```
$ kubectl expose pod app3-86499b66d-dfwf7 --port 8000 --name app3
service/app3 exposed
```

But in this case the pod is referenced using pod-template-hash, so when recreated, the service won't longer work.

This is why much better option is to expose a deployment:

```
$ kubectl expose deployment app3 --port 8000
service/app3 exposed
```

And now you can access it using pord-forward funcitonality like following:

```
$ kubectl port-forward service/app3 8000:8000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8000 -> 8000
Forwarding from [::1]:8000 -> 8000
```

The second approach additionally takes case of loadbalancing, so if you had more than 1 replica, it would handle traffic distribution for you.